# NumberFormatException being thrown by Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java

For my assignment, I'm trying to read a sequence of integers into an array and calculate a few things about the array. I'm restricted to using InputStreamReader and BufferedReader to read from the file, and Integer.parseInt() is throwing NumberFormatException after the first line read.

Everything works if I input each number individually by keyboard, but it doesn't work at all if I try and read directly from the file.

Here's the code so far

```
int[] array = new int[20];

    try {
        int x, count = 0;
        do{
            x = Integer.parseInt((new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine()));
            array[count] = x;
            count++;
        }
        while (x != 0);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

The case to be tested is

```
33
-55
-44
12312
2778
-3
-2
53211
-1
44
0
```

When I try and copy/paste the whole test case, the program only reads the first line and then throws
NumberFormatException. Why does readLine() only read the first value and ignore everything else?s

Comment: BufferedReader is not actually throwing the NumberFormatException, it's another method on the same line. You should be able to see that if you read further up the stack trace (which you have not provided - please provide a stack trace in future questions involving Java exceptions).

Comment: Ah, I see you are hiding the stack trace, so no wonder you can't see it. Never do this in a catch: `System.out.println(e)`. Instead, do `e.printStackTrace()` - or simply get rid of the catch altogether - it's probably not needed.

Answer (score 4):

You are reopening `System.in` each time. I don't know what this does but I assume it can't be good.

Instead, you should use **one** `BufferedReader`, and in your loop, read lines one by one from it.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I think this is happening is that you create a reader, read one line, and then on the next iteration you create a new one, which is empty but still tries to read, therefore it reads "", passes it to the parser and `Integer.parseInt()` throws NumberFormatException because it can't be parsed. The correct way to do this is:

```
int[] array = new int[20];

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        int x, count = 0;
        do {
            String s = reader.readLine();
            x = Integer.parseInt(s);
            array[count] = x;
            count++;
        }
        while (x != 0);
    } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```